# Why Trace.WriteLine() doesn't work from the ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: logging, azure, azure-web-roles

I've just created small Windows Azure application (it's just only one WebRole) and I'm testing it in the Windows Azure Compute Emulator (running in debug mode from VisualStudio).

**But application logging still doesn't work for me.** The issue is just that I'm able to log the message from the `WebRole.Run()` method -- I can see "foo bar" string in the Emulator console when the `Run()` meth is called (web role starting).

But *nothing happens when I'm trying to log from ASP.NET MVC controller action method* (i.e. there is no log entry in the emulator console although controller action method is invoked by my HTTP request and works well).

In the `WebRole` class:

```
public override void Run()
{
    Trace.WriteLine("foo bar", "Information");
    base.Run();
}
```

In the ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
    Trace.WriteLine("redirecting ...", "Information");
    // ...
    return RedirectPermanent(url);
}
```

What could be the problem? Why `Trace.WriteLine()` doesn't work for controllers? I've ASP.NET web API controller as well as classic ASP.NET MVC controller and it is the same.

Or am I completely wrong and application logging should be performed in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the situation addressed in the blog post at http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2012/11/18/how-to-enable-asp-net-trace-statements-to-show-up-in-windows-azure-compute-emulator/

Comment: Yes perhaps it is the same issue. It helped me a lot but still logging in the emulator seems bit tricky to me... Still doesn't work well. Anyway, thank you! +1